# Multiple Amcharts are not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I try to load multiple amcharts charts on one page. The charts work perfectly with both Chrome and Edge. Firefox shows only the first graph and not the other graphs. Hopefully someone can show me how I can solve this problem.

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/3xa9qrk1/) I have made three amcharts graphs, where I have given the variables for each graph a number. Not sure if this is necessary. If I open this example in Chrome or Edge then all three graphs works but not in Firefox. Hopefully with the help of this example you can find out what the problem is.

HTML

```
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv1"></div>
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
<div id="chartdiv3"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var iconPath = "M53.5,476c0,14,6.833,21,20.5,21s20.5-7,20.5-21V287h21v189c0,14,6.834,21,20.5,21 c13.667,0,20.5-7,20.5-21V154h10v116c0,7.334,2.5,12.667,7.5,16s10.167,3.333,15.5,0s8-8.667,8-16V145c0-13.334-4.5-23.667-13.5-31 s-21.5-11-37.5-11h-82c-15.333,0-27.833,3.333-37.5,10s-14.5,17-14.5,31v133c0,6,2.667,10.333,8,13s10.5,2.667,15.5,0s7.5-7,7.5-13 V154h10V476 M61.5,42.5c0,11.667,4.167,21.667,12.5,30S92.333,85,104,85s21.667-4.167,30-12.5S146.5,54,146.5,42 c0-11.335-4.167-21.168-12.5-29.5C125.667,4.167,115.667,0,104,0S82.333,4.167,74,12.5S61.5,30.833,61.5,42.5z"



var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv1", am4charts.SlicedChart);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect

chart.data = [{
    "name": "The first",
    "value": 354
}, {
    "name": "The second",
    "value": 245
}, {
    "name": "The third",
    "value": 187
}, {
    "name": "The fourth",
    "value": 123
}, {
    "name": "The fifth",
    "value": 87
}, {
    "name": "The sixth",
    "value": 45
}, {
    "name": "The seventh",
    "value": 23
}];

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PictorialStackedSeries());
series.dataFields.value = "value";
series.dataFields.category = "name";
series.alignLabels = true;

series.maskSprite.path = iconPath;
series.ticks.template.locationX = 1;
series.ticks.template.locationY = 0.5;

series.labelsContainer.width = 200;

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "left";
chart.legend.valign = "bottom";

//chart2

var iconPath2 = "M53.5,476c0,14,6.833,21,20.5,21s20.5-7,20.5-21V287h21v189c0,14,6.834,21,20.5,21 c13.667,0,20.5-7,20.5-21V154h10v116c0,7.334,2.5,12.667,7.5,16s10.167,3.333,15.5,0s8-8.667,8-16V145c0-13.334-4.5-23.667-13.5-31 s-21.5-11-37.5-11h-82c-15.333,0-27.833,3.333-37.5,10s-14.5,17-14.5,31v133c0,6,2.667,10.333,8,13s10.5,2.667,15.5,0s7.5-7,7.5-13 V154h10V476 M61.5,42.5c0,11.667,4.167,21.667,12.5,30S92.333,85,104,85s21.667-4.167,30-12.5S146.5,54,146.5,42 c0-11.335-4.167-21.168-12.5-29.5C125.667,4.167,115.667,0,104,0S82.333,4.167,74,12.5S61.5,30.833,61.5,42.5z"



var chart2 = am4core.create("chartdiv2", am4charts.SlicedChart);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect

chart2.data = [{
    "name": "The first",
    "value": 354
}, {
    "name": "The second",
    "value": 245
}, {
    "name": "The third",
    "value": 187
}, {
    "name": "The fourth",
    "value": 123
}, {
    "name": "The fifth",
    "value": 87
}, {
    "name": "The sixth",
    "value": 45
}, {
    "name": "The seventh",
    "value": 23
}];

var series2 = chart2.series.push(new am4charts.PictorialStackedSeries());
series2.dataFields.value = "value";
series2.dataFields.category = "name";
series2.alignLabels = true;

series2.maskSprite.path = iconPath2;
series2.ticks.template.locationX = 1;
series2.ticks.template.locationY = 0.5;

series2.labelsContainer.width = 200;

chart2.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart2.legend.position = "left";
chart2.legend.valign = "bottom";

//chart 3
var iconPath3 = `"M53.5,476c0,14,6.833,21,20.5,21s20.5-7,20.5-21V287h21v189c0,14,6.834,21,20.5,21 c13.667,0,20.5-7,20.5-21V154h10v116c0,7.334,2.5,12.667,7.5,16s10.167,3.333,15.5,0s8-8.667,8-16V145c0-13.334-4.5-23.667-13.5-31 s-21.5-11-37.5-11h-82c-15.333,0-27.833,3.333-37.5,10s-14.5,17-14.5,31v133c0,6,2.667,10.333,8,13s10.5,2.667,15.5,0s7.5-7,7.5-13 V154h10V476 M61.5,42.5c0,11.667,4.167,21.667,12.5,30S92.333,85,104,85s21.667-4.167,30-12.5S146.5,54,146.5,42 c0-11.335-4.167-21.168-12.5-29.5C125.667,4.167,115.667,0,104,0S82.333,4.167,74,12.5S61.5,30.833,61.5,42.5z"`

var chart3 = am4core.create("chartdiv3", am4charts.SlicedChart);
chart.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this makes initial fade in effect

chart3.data = [{
    "name": "The first",
    "value": 354
}, {
    "name": "The second",
    "value": 245
}, {
    "name": "The third",
    "value": 187
}, {
    "name": "The fourth",
    "value": 123
}, {
    "name": "The fifth",
    "value": 87
}, {
    "name": "The sixth",
    "value": 45
}, {
    "name": "The seventh",
    "value": 23
}];

var series3 = chart3.series.push(new am4charts.PictorialStackedSeries());
series3.dataFields.value = "value";
series3.dataFields.category = "name";
series3.alignLabels = true;

series3.maskSprite.path = iconPath3;
series3.ticks.template.locationX = 1;
series3.ticks.template.locationY = 0.5;

series3.labelsContainer.width = 200;

chart3.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart3.legend.position = "left";
chart3.legend.valign = "bottom";
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#chartdiv2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#chartdiv3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There's [an open issue on github](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1496) that seems to be related. The developers are looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved! Thanks to the developers of AmCharts.