# Multiple amCharts 4 in firefox

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I try to load multiple amcharts charts on one page. The charts work perfectly with both Chrome and Edge. Firefox shows only the first graph and not the other graphs. Hopefully someone can show me how I can solve this problem.

previously [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258412/multiple-amcharts-are-not-working-in-firefox) does not have a visible solution

In this [example](https://codepen.io/lossburg/pen/VwXKaBo) I have made 2 amcharts graphs. If I open this example in Chrome or Edge then all graphs works but not in Firefox. Hopefully with the help of this example you can find out what the problem is.

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var gantt = am4core.create("gantt", am4charts.XYChart);
gantt.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in
gantt.paddingRight = 30;
gantt.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";

var colorSet = new am4core.ColorSet();
colorSet.saturation = 0.4;

gantt.data = [
  {
    category: 'First',
    fromDate: '01.01.2022',
    toDate: '01.03.2022',
    fromDateReal: '01.02.2022',
    toDateReal: '01.04.2022',
    colorPlan: colorSet.getIndex(0).brighten(0),
    colorReal: colorSet.getIndex(8).brighten(0)
  },
  {
    category: 'Second',
    fromDate: '01.02.2022',
    toDate: '01.05.2022',
    fromDateReal: '01.01.2022',
    toDateReal: '01.06.2022',
    colorPlan: colorSet.getIndex(0).brighten(0),
    colorReal: colorSet.getIndex(8).brighten(0)
  }
 ]


var categoryAxisGantt = gantt.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxisGantt.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxisGantt.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxisGantt.renderer.inversed = true;
var yLabelGantt = categoryAxisGantt.renderer.labels.template;
yLabelGantt.wrap = true;
yLabelGantt.maxWidth = 200;

var dateAxisGantt = gantt.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxisGantt.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
dateAxisGantt.renderer.minGridDistance = 70;
dateAxisGantt.min = (new Date(2022, 01, 01)).getTime();
dateAxisGantt.strictMinMax = true;
dateAxisGantt.renderer.tooltipLocation = 0;

var rangeGantt = dateAxisGantt.axisRanges.create();
rangeGantt.date = new Date();
rangeGantt.grid.stroke = am4core.color("red");
rangeGantt.grid.strokeWidth = 2;
rangeGantt.grid.strokeOpacity = 1;


function createGanttSeries(start, end, category, name, color){
    var series1Gantt = gantt.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series1Gantt.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(80);
    series1Gantt.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}\n{category}: {openDateX} - {dateX}";

    series1Gantt.dataFields.openDateX = start;
    series1Gantt.dataFields.dateX = end;
    series1Gantt.dataFields.categoryY = category;
    series1Gantt.name = name
    series1Gantt.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = color; // get color from data
    series1Gantt.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = color;
    series1Gantt.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
}

//план
createGanttSeries("fromDate", "toDate", "category", "План", "colorPlan");

//факт
createGanttSeries("fromDateReal", "toDateReal", "category", "Факт", "colorReal");


gantt.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();



// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("dds", am4charts.XYChart);
let title = chart.titles.create();
title.text = "ДДС";
title.fontSize = 25;
title.marginBottom = 30;
// Export
chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();

    



var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.dateFormatter = new am4core.DateFormatter();
chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yy";


var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());



var columnSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
columnSeries.name = "ДДС (план)";
columnSeries.dataFields.valueY = "val";
columnSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";

columnSeries.columns.template.tooltipText = "[#fff font-size: 15px]{name} {dateX}:\n[/][#fff font-size: 20px]{valueY}[/] [#fff]{additional}[/]"
columnSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.fillOpacity = "fillOpacity";
columnSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "stroke";
columnSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.strokeWidth = "strokeWidth";
columnSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.strokeDasharray = "columnDash";
columnSeries.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";  

chart.data = [
  {
    "date": "06.10.2022",
    "val": 143566570.46,
    "total": 143566570.46
  },
  {
    "date": "09.25.2022",
    "val": 35891642.62,
    "total": 179458213.08
  }
];
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#gantt {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#dds {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="gantt"></div>
<div id="dds"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `inputDateFormat` for your second chart.

```
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "MM.dd.yyyy";
```

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

var gantt = am4core.create("gantt", am4charts.XYChart);
gantt.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 0; // this creates initial fade-in
gantt.paddingRight = 30;
gantt.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";

var colorSet = new am4core.ColorSet();
colorSet.saturation = 0.4;

gantt.data = [
  {
    category: 'First',
    fromDate: '01.01.2022',
    toDate: '01.03.2022',
    fromDateReal: '01.02.2022',
    toDateReal: '01.04.2022',
    colorPlan: colorSet.getIndex(0).brighten(0),
    colorReal: colorSet.getIndex(8).brighten(0)
  },
  {
    category: 'Second',
    fromDate: '01.02.2022',
    toDate: '01.05.2022',
    fromDateReal: '01.01.2022',
    toDateReal: '01.06.2022',
    colorPlan: colorSet.getIndex(0).brighten(0),
    colorReal: colorSet.getIndex(8).brighten(0)
  }
 ]


var categoryAxisGantt = gantt.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxisGantt.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxisGantt.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxisGantt.renderer.inversed = true;
var yLabelGantt = categoryAxisGantt.renderer.labels.template;
yLabelGantt.wrap = true;
yLabelGantt.maxWidth = 200;

var dateAxisGantt = gantt.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxisGantt.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";
dateAxisGantt.renderer.minGridDistance = 70;
dateAxisGantt.min = (new Date(2022, 01, 01)).getTime();
dateAxisGantt.strictMinMax = true;
dateAxisGantt.renderer.tooltipLocation = 0;

var rangeGantt = dateAxisGantt.axisRanges.create();
rangeGantt.date = new Date();
rangeGantt.grid.stroke = am4core.color("red");
rangeGantt.grid.strokeWidth = 2;
rangeGantt.grid.strokeOpacity = 1;


function createGanttSeries(start, end, category, name, color){
    var series1Gantt = gantt.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series1Gantt.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(80);
    series1Gantt.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}\n{category}: {openDateX} - {dateX}";

    series1Gantt.dataFields.openDateX = start;
    series1Gantt.dataFields.dateX = end;
    series1Gantt.dataFields.categoryY = category;
    series1Gantt.name = name
    series1Gantt.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = color; // get color from data
    series1Gantt.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = color;
    series1Gantt.columns.template.strokeOpacity = 1;
}

//план
createGanttSeries("fromDate", "toDate", "category", "План", "colorPlan");

//факт
createGanttSeries("fromDateReal", "toDateReal", "category", "Факт", "colorReal");


gantt.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();



// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("dds", am4charts.XYChart);
let title = chart.titles.create();
title.text = "ДДС";
title.fontSize = 25;
title.marginBottom = 30;
// Export
chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();

chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "MM.dd.yyyy";



var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.dateFormatter = new am4core.DateFormatter();
chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yy";


var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());



var columnSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
columnSeries.name = "ДДС (план)";
columnSeries.dataFields.valueY = "val";
columnSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";

columnSeries.columns.template.tooltipText = "[#fff font-size: 15px]{name} {dateX}:\n[/][#fff font-size: 20px]{valueY}[/] [#fff]{additional}[/]"
columnSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.fillOpacity = "fillOpacity";
columnSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "stroke";
columnSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.strokeWidth = "strokeWidth";
columnSeries.columns.template.propertyFields.strokeDasharray = "columnDash";
columnSeries.tooltip.label.textAlign = "middle";  

chart.data = [
  {
    "date": "06.10.2022",
    "val": 143566570.46,
    "total": 143566570.46
  },
  {
    "date": "09.25.2022",
    "val": 35891642.62,
    "total": 179458213.08
  }
];
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#gantt {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#dds {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="gantt"></div>
<div id="dds"></div>
```

Comment: This does not help

Comment: It works for me when I add it: https://jsfiddle.net/2du4vnz9/. Also embedded above. You need to provide a lot more details on what doesn't work.

Comment: there are 2 charts. In Chrome - you can see 2 charts, in FF - only first. No matter what chart placed first and no matter what dateFormatter is (https://codepen.io/lossburg/pen/VwXKaBo).

Comment: That's the thing. I can see the second chart in Firefox with the dateformatter ([screenshot of your codepen in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWs3U.png)); I don't see the second chart when the second dateformatter is missing. Are you using the latest version of Firefox? Do you have any console errors? Have you cleared your browser cache lately?